# Media Library plugins for better file management?

Tags: media-library

Is there any plugin to extend the basic functionality of the Media Library for websites with a lot of media content?

A folder structure would be awesome...at the moment I am using the [Media Tags plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-tags/) but I am wondering if there is something more powerful around.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: You can use Media File Manager Advanced to create subfolders in you library http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-file-manager-advanced/

Comment: I think this is a really exceptionally good question, and can not believe that it has been closed as off topic.  Here we are two years later, and Wordpress still lacks this basic functionality.

Comment: Media Library Categories (http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-media-library-categories/) does exactly what you need and nothing more. You have categories (standard wp taxonomy that applies to media files), which act exactly like nested folders, with the added bonus that you can have one file in more than one categories/folders. If you like this way of doing things but want even more power, use Enhanced Media Library (http://wordpress.org/plugins/enhanced-media-library/) - awesome as well but maybe "too powerful".

Comment: This is indeed a good and legal question as long as wordpress doesen't offer user managed folders (like almost every other cms out there). @toscho why did you closed this topic? I vote for reopening.

Comment: @Hexodus I closed it, because plugin recommendation questions are off topic and this question received too many spam answers.

Comment: @toscho Oh I see, the answers are indeed a bit out off track.

Comment: @Hexodus You should the answers I had to delete …

Comment: What the heck?! Why would anyone vote this question as off topic?

Answer (score 3):

I am using [Media Categories](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-library-categories/) It has folder structures.

Answer (score 1):

The Media Library is in its current state indeed a weak area of WordPress. If you only have images as media, I recommend the excellent and popular [NEXTGen-Gallery Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/)
Keep in mind though that it lives separate from the original media library.

Comment: Indeed, I use ngg and there is no way to interact with the media lib. Most annoying is that the preview image can only be selected from the media lib, but all my images are organized with ngg.